# Как в Laravel удалить файл сессии?

Tags: laravel

Пытался удалять с помощью нижеприложенного кода, не помогло:

```
<?php    
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;    
File::Delete('/storage/framework/sessions//' . session()->GetId());
```

Comment: Зачем? А вы уверены что у вас сессия в файлах храниться? Какая ОС? Версия PHP?

Comment: `\Session::getHandler()->destroy($sessionId);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для удаления одного поля с сессии попробуйте вот такой код:

```
$request->session()->forget('key');
```

А чтобы удалить все поля с сессии попробуйте вот такой код

```
$request->session()->flush();
```